# Python LIfe Expectancy

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to use panda to calculate life expectanc with complex equations.
Multiply or divide column by column is not difficult to do. 
My data is

```
   A      b     
1  0.99  1000
2  0.95   =0.99*1000=990
3  0.93   = 0.95*990
```

Field A is populated and field be has only the 1000
Field b (b2) = A1*b1 
Tried shift function, got result for b2 only and the rest zeros any help please thanks mazin

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please ask a question with a [complete, minimal, and verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) What have you tried? What are you trying to accomplish? What happens instead?

Comment: Thanks work fantastic regards mazin

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, if you're starting with:

```
>>> df
      A       b
0  0.99  1000.0
1  0.95     NaN
2  0.93     NaN
```

Then you can do:

```
df.loc[df.b.isnull(),'b'] = (df.A.cumprod()*1000).shift()

>>> df
      A       b
0  0.99  1000.0
1  0.95   990.0
2  0.93   940.5
```

Or more generally:

```
df['b'] = (df.A.cumprod()*df.b.iloc[0]).shift().fillna(df.b.iloc[0])
```

Comment: Thanks will check Monday at work and keep you informed. Appreciate your help.